# WinRT XamlReader.Load XamlParseException from SampleData

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10

I'm using some sample data generated by Blend 2015 in a Windows 10 app.  I want to use the sample data at runtime.

The sampledata xaml file is as follows:

```
<ViewModels:HomeViewModel xmlns:ViewModels="using:ForeStory.ViewModels" Caption="Euismod fames diam sem sit" IsDataLoaded="True" >
<ViewModels:HomeViewModel.Events>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Sed aliquam cras" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Vestibulum nam"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Dis curae aenean quisque" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Class integer maecenas"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Donec etiam fusce vivamus praesent" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Duis curabitur adipiscing"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Lorem aliquam" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Parturient nunc phasellus mauris"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Blandit vestibulum dictumst nullam" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Consequat accumsan aliquet bibendum est"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Amet commodo leo" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Convallis hac aptent morbi auctor"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Dictum cubilia mus facilisi ante" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Dignissim congue conubia cursus eleifend"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Arcu egestas" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Nulla faucibus habitant proin dapibus"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Libero augue facilisis" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Lectus elementum nec"/>
    <ViewModels:Event Category="Dolor vestibulum per sed" DateOfEvent="04/24/2015 10:21:19" Title="Inceptos ligula litora non"/>
</ViewModels:HomeViewModel.Events>
```

When I go to load the xaml using XamlReader.Load, I receive this error:

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: The property '%0' was not found in type '%1'. [Line: 1 Position: 73]
```

I'm assuming this is a namespacing issue at runtime, but I have no idea how to fix this with the new "using" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load sample data via `XamlReader.Load` -- that is used to read XAML UI. Typically Blend will create a class for you that encapsulates the data, but if you need to load it manually you should use [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br244248.aspx).

Comment: I created my sample data from a view model and have not modified it at all.  I've now switched my code to use the LoadComponent method, but still get the same results.  It seems like it isn't finding the namespace of the view model when parsing the xaml. It bombs on the first custom property, so in this case, it is bombing on Caption.  I don't see any way of adding a namespace to the LoadComponent method either.

Comment: Did you change your namespace or the name of the type? Can you just use the auto-generated class directly (rather than trying to load the data yourself)?

Comment: I haven't changed the namespace or the name of the type. I'm not seeing any auto-generated classes.  Does it show up in solution explorer? It created a sampledata folder, but only shows a xaml file, with no code behind.